# sending uchar* over winsock2

Tags: c++, winsock

I have a uchar buffer that needs to be sent.  It can't be converted to char.

I have a sample project that casts:

```
send(SOCKET s, void *buf, size_t length) { return send(s, buf, length, 0);
```

My attempt is:

```
err = send( ConnectSocket, (void*)buf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
```

The only thing I know to be different is the version of VS(2008).

That line will not compile in my 2010 project.  The error is cannot convert paramerter 2 void* to const char *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
err = send( ConnectSocket, (char*)buf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
```

Comment: Wouldn't that sign the buffer?  These values cannot be signed.

Comment: @Bluebaron Why should it? It just casts the pointer, which gets ultimately cast to `void*` and therefore hasn't any notion of signedness anyway. The cast doesn't just alter the data it points to and the `send` function doesn't care about any type, it just copies raw memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wants a `const char*` and not just a `char*`, you cannot just pass a plain `void*`, as C++ doesn't support implicit casting to/from `void*`. So you have to explicitly convert it to `char*` or `const char*`:

```
err = send( ConnectSocket, (const char*)buf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
```

Keep in mind that casting the pointer doesn't magically change the signedness of the data in your buffer, because send doesn't care about any signedness and just copies raw data.

But as to why it worked with VS2008 I don't know, because C++ doesn't cast to/from `void*` implicitly by standard. Maybe `send` was defined differently (I doubt that) or the rules were just laxed (non-standard-conformant). Or maybe you compiled it as C, which in turn casts to/from `void*` implicitly, by standard.

Comment: @Bluebaron Ok, I updated it. I was confused by you writing a wrapper for the native `send` and then using the native `send` instead of your wrapper. I just thought your second line used your wrapper function.